# how can I add ajax notice when the product was successfully added to cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

I have Magento 1.9.1 and I installed an extension that automatically add product to cart with ajax, after the product was successfully added to cart this extension display a notification: Your product "NAME" was added to cart. I want to change this notification with entire product details, like product image, sku, name, description ... Can anyone tell me where to start? My notification function look like this:

```
function notifyBar(msg) {      
    jQuery('.notification').show('fast');
    jQuery('.notification').html("<div id='note'>"+msg+"</div>");     
     setTimeout(function(){         
        jQuery(".notification").hide('slow');
      },1500);       
 }
```

I will add here the entire Observer.php code:

```
 public function addToCartEvent($observer)
{
    $request = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest();
    if (!$request->getParam('in_cart') && !$request->getParam('is_checkout'))
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
        $subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $shippingTaxamount = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount');

        // get coupon discounted value            

        $totals = $quote->getTotals(); //Total object
        if (isset($totals['discount']) && $totals['discount']->getValue())
        {
            $discount = Mage::helper('core')->currency($totals['discount']->getValue()); //Discount value if applied
        }
        else
        {
            $discount = '';
        }

        //get discount value end     

        $xitems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $max = 0;
        $lastItem = null;
        foreach ($xitems as $xitem)
        {
            if ($xitem->getId() > $max)
            {
                $max = $xitem->getId();
                $lastItem = $xitem;
                $attributeSetModel1 = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set")->load($lastItem->getProduct()->getAttributeSetId());
                $attributeSetName1 = $attributeSetModel1->getAttributeSetName();
                $parentIds1 = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($lastItem->getProduct()->getId());
                if ($lastItem->getProduct()->getTypeId() == 'simple' && empty($parentIds1) && $attributeSetName1 == 'Default')
                {
                    $child = $lastItem;
                }
                else
                {
                    $child = $lastItem->getOptionByCode('simple_product')->getProduct();
                }
            }
        }



        $html = '';
        $productser = '';
        foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
        {
            if ($lastItem)
            {
                $xproduct = $lastItem->getProduct();
                $xproductsku = $xproduct->getSku();
                $xproductname = $xproduct->getName();
                $xproductqty = $xproduct->getQty();
                $xproductprice = $xproduct->getPrice();
                $xproducturl = $xproduct->getUrl();
            }






            $productOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
            if ($productOptions)
            {
                if (isset($productOptions['options']))
                {
                    foreach ($productOptions['options'] as $_option)
                    {
                        $productser = $_option['option_id'] . ',' . $_option['option_value'];
                    }
                }
                $superAttrString = '';
                if (isset($productOptions['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute']))
                {
                    foreach ($productOptions['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute'] as $key => $_superAttr)
                    {
                        $attr = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($key);
                        $label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_superAttr);
                        $superAttrString .= '<dt> ' . $attr->getAttributeCode() . ' </dt> <dd> ' . $label . ' </dd>';
                    }
                }
                if ($superAttrString):
                    $superAttrString . '&qty=1';
                endif;
            }

            $productid = $item->getId();
            $html .='<li id="li-' . $productid . '">';
            $product_id = $item->getProduct()->getId();
            $productsku = $item->getSku();
            $productname = $item->getName();
            $productqty = $item->getQty();
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            $url = Mage::getUrl(
                            'checkout/cart/deleteqty', array(
                        'id' => $productid,
                        Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => Mage::helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl()
                            )
            );


            $count = $quote->getItemsCount();
            $html .='<div class="item-thumbnail">';
            if ($item->hasProductUrl()):
                $html .='<a href="' . $item->getUrl() . '" title="' . $item->getName() . '" class="product-image"><img src="' . Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail') . '" width="50" height="50" alt="' . $this->escapeHtml($item->getName()) . '" /></a>';
            else:
                $html .='<span><img src="' . Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail') . '" width="50" height="50" alt="' . $item->getName() . '" /></span>';
            endif;
            $html .='</div>';
            $html .='<div class="mini-basket-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="mini-cart-name">
                    <a class="item-name" href="' . $item->getUrl() . '">' . $productname . '</a> <span class="item-price"><span class="price">$' . $item->getPrice() . '</span></span>
            <div class="truncated_full_value">
    <dl class="item-options">
        <dd class="truncated">
            <div class="truncated_full_value">
                <dl class="item-options">
                    ' . $superAttrString . '
                </dl>
            </div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
 </div>

    <div class="product-cart-sku">SKU: # ' . $productsku . '</div>
        <div class="product-qty">Quantity: ' . $productqty . '</div>
                </div>  
               </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>';
            $html .='</li>';
        }

        $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')
                ->setProductName($observer->getProduct()->getName())
                ->setCarttotal($grandTotal)
                ->setCartsubtotal($subTotal)
                ->setCartcount($count)
                ->setDiscount($discount)
                ->setShippingtaxamount($shippingTaxamount)
                ->setCartitem($html)
                ->setMessage(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('%s was added into cart.', $observer->getProduct()->getName()));

        //append updated blocks

        $_response->addUpdatedBlocks($_response);
        $_response->send();
    }

    if ($request->getParam('is_checkout'))
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
        $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')
                ->setProductName($observer->getProduct()->getName())
                ->setMessage(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('%s was added into cart.', $observer->getProduct()->getName()));
        $_response->send();
    }
}

public function updateItemEvent($observer)
{
    $request = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest();
    if (!$request->getParam('in_cart') && !$request->getParam('is_checkout'))
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
        $subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
        $shippingTaxamount = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount');

        // get coupon discounted value            

        $totals = $quote->getTotals(); //Total object
        if (isset($totals['discount']) && $totals['discount']->getValue())
        {
            $discount = Mage::helper('core')->currency($totals['discount']->getValue()); //Discount value if applied
        }
        else
        {
            $discount = '';
        }

        //get discount value end                

        $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')
                ->setCarttotal($grandTotal)
                ->setCartsubtotal($subTotal)
                ->setShippingtaxamount($shippingTaxamount)
                ->setDiscount($discount)
                ->setMessage(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Item was updated'));

        //append updated blocks
        $_response->addUpdatedBlocks($_response);
        $_response->send();
    }

    if ($request->getParam('is_checkout'))
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
        $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')
                ->setMessage(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Item was updated'));
        $_response->send();
    }
}

public function getConfigurableOptions($observer)
{

    $is_ajax = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('ajax');
    if ($is_ajax)
    {
        $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response');
        $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response');
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
        if (!$product->isConfigurable() && !$product->getTypeId() == 'bundle')
        {
            return false;
            exit;
        }

        //append configurable options block

        $_response->addConfigurableOptionsBlock($_response);
        $_response->send();
    }

    return;
}

public function getGroupProductOptions()
{

    $id = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('product');
    $options = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('super_group');
    if ($id)
    {

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
        if ($product->getData())
        {
            if ($product->getTypeId() == 'grouped' && !$options)
            {
                $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response');
                Mage::register('product', $product);
                Mage::register('current_product', $product);
                //add group product's items block
                $_response->addGroupProductItemsBlock($_response);
                $_response->send();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: you have to find the page where the `notifyBar(msg)` function is getting called, than you can change the `msg` variable as per your desired message

Comment: Hi thank you for your quick response I change my code, please take a look, I add the function there. But how can I add that variables to get the current product image, name, description, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')    
   ->setProductName($observer->getProduct()->getName())  
   ->setMessage(Mage::helper('checkout')
   ->__('%s was added into cart. Description : %s', $observer->getProduct()->getName(),$observer->getProduct()->getDescription()));
```

below list can be used for different product attributes

```
getShortDescription(); //product's short description
getDescription(); // product's long description
getName(); //product name
getPrice(); //product's regular Price
getSpecialPrice(); //product's special Price
getProductUrl(); //product url
getImageUrl(); //product's image url
getSmallImageUrl(); //product's small image url
getThumbnailUrl(); //product's thumbnail image url
```

let me know it works or not.. regards

Comment: Thank you, your code work perfect but I have a small problem, when a configurable product is add to cart the notification display the name of configurable, not associated product name. for example if I select a custom optiom: red and size small, the notification not display this.

Comment: @user4354004 if it works for you than please voteup and select it, and yeah for what you are looking for custom attribute can be little bit tricky, try printing the data which is being posted when you add the product to the cart, that will give you the `code` or `id` of the `custom attribute`.. and than `$attribute = $observer->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute_code');`